# What kind of behavior "<<<"?

Tags: bash, shell

I get the following code to get a fingerprint from private key of OpenSSH.

```
$ key=`ssh-keygen -yf ~/.ssh/id_rsa`; ssh-keygen -lf /dev/stdin <<<$key
```

However, I do not know <<< $key syntax.
What behavior is this? Is there a web site that explains this syntax?

Comment: That's a [Here String](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).

Comment: @TrisNefzger, no, `<"$key"` is reading from a file named by the expansion of `"$key"`, which is a different operation.

Comment: There is a site called google. If you type "bash triple less than" it can take you to many magical places that tells you what it does...

Comment: It's not reasonable to have a "what is X?" question for every single language feature X. For that reason, I'm skeptical that questions of this form are worthwhile contributions to the knowledge base.

Comment: Open `man bash` and then search on `<<<`.

Comment: @TrisNefzger, ...a man page already linked to at a more authoritative location by Etan, and quoted directly in an answer by Mike.

Comment: Looking it up in http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash it says "<<<word is a variant of here documents : The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input". In this case it looks like $key is the key created in the previous command and ssh-keygen -lf  shows the fingerprint of  the public key file specified by the argument of the -f option per http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

> #### Here Strings
>
> A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> ```
>   <<<word
> ```
>
> The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.

Comment: thanks, I Although Here-Document knew, I did not know the existence of the Here-String.